# Trying to prevent this Deadlock from happening in my .NET code on SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, deadlock

A deadlock is occurring during my integration tests for some C# code that is testing my SQL queries against a SQL Server.

- Software: SQL Server 2012
- Database: `READ COMMITTED ISOLATION` is set to `ON`

I have two tests that are fighting each other as this happens in parallel.

Test 1 (Pseudo C# code)

```
using (start a new transaction)
{
    foreach Person in the People-Collection
    {
        Insert this Person into the DB and grab the ID of this inserted person.
        => INSERT INTO [dbo].[People] (...) VALUES (...);
           SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);
    }

    Now, count how many people are in the DB right now (because there might have been more, from before we inserted these temp people).
        => SELECT COUNT(PersonId) FROM [dbo].[People]
}
// end transaction (which rolls back because of no explicit transaction.commit)
```

Test 2

```
using (start a new transaction)
{
    Update a person
    => UPDATE [dbo].[People]
       SET    .....
       WHERE  PersonId = @personId
}
// end transaction which auto rolls back.
```

So *I'm guessing* that the following is happening:

- Test1 runs the INSERT/SELECT
- Test2 runs the UPDATE (waits for test1 to finish)
- Test1 finishes but now runs the SELECT COUNT(..)

and for some reason, test1 is waiting for test2 to complete it's update but test2 can't update (for reasons I can't imagine).

I would have thought the following *should* have occurred:

- Test1 starts running (and in a TRANSACTION).
- Test2 starts running .. and notices that there's a transaction running so it either waits for that transaction to complete *OR* can figure out that it's update has *nothing* to do with test1's transaction so it updates.
- Test1 eventually completes.

Obviously, I don't get what is happening :(

Index
The deadlock graph lists a particular index as a cause of grief. Here's the index:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[People] ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_People_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Can someone make some suggestions to how I can fix this, please?

NOTE: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/8a3fe15bec04172b2d165fabf22ddcd9) contains the full deadlock graph as a reference.

EDIT 1: Added `using` statement code for better understanding of logic/flow.
EDIT 2: Added index schema/code

Comment: >>end transaction (which rolls back because of no explicit transaction.commit)

Are you doing an explicit rollback?

Comment: No. the code is in a .net `using` scope, so it auto-rollsback because there is not explicit `commit()`;

Comment: What indexes are on this table? What does the query plan for `SELECT COUNT(PersonId) FROM [dbo].[People]` look like?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Use `Output Inserted...`

Comment: You can add `with nolock` hint to your select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an index on the name column, so the update behaves as a delete+insert for locking/IO purposes.

The deadlock graph shows Test1 waiting to acquire a `RangeS-S` lock to count all rows while holding a `RangeX-X` lock on the inserted row(s). It needs a shared lock over the entire table to count the rows and an exclusive lock for the inserted rows (not sure why it's using a range lock).

At the same time Test2 is waiting to acquire a `RangeI-N` lock to insert the new name row while holding a `X` lock on the removed old name row.

I would suggest one of the following:

- Create a narrow unique index on the primary key(`PersonID?`) field - this index would not need locking for updates, can be used to do a fast count(*) and it's quite cheap to maintain. It also improves concurrency and performance of foreign key integrity checks (for this to take effect the FK-s referencing `[People]` table have to be re-created).
- Change the locking of the count query (if business requirements allow) - e.g. use `WITH(READCOMMITTED)` table hint or do it after committing the inserts.
- Run the count query before the inserts and increment it by the inserted row count (this might be bad for concurrency because it holds a shared lock on the entire table)

Comment: Hi @pent - thank you kindly for your answer. Is there any chance you can please elaborate on your answer. I really don't understand what that means right now. Are these locks good? Should they be doing this? Are there some other suggestions to how I could improve things to remove these problems?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the technical points to your answer ... so as I work through that, i'll be posting the odd question. Firstly - why would the code be using `IX_People_Name` as the index when I'm not doing any `WHERE` clauses against that particular field?

Comment: The index needs to be updated for the new/changed rows. The count query is using the index most likely because it's the smallest (narrowest) index on the table - it's the fastest way to enumerate all the rows.

Comment: Why would the count be using the `IX_People_Name` index instead of the Primary Key ? wouldn't the Primary Key be the smallest (narrowest) index on that table?

Comment: The primary key is most probably a clustered index - it contains all the columns, i.e. the entire table.

Comment: How about using an INDEX HINT for the `COUNT` statement, instead of creating another index (like you suggestion #1). This `COUNT` is only used in a TEST suite. Secondly, you suggest this: "_It also improves concurrency and performance of foreign key integrity checks_" .. so does this mean you personally create these narrow indexes for FK's, in your own Db's ?

Comment: A `WITH(READCOMMITTED)` hint would work - with `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` on it doesn't cause a deadlock. I personally create these narrow indexes only on some high-concurrency tables that also have many references to them (a People table looks like a good candiate).